# TYPO3 7.6.18. Pagination widget. Always page 1 displayed

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a question about the pagination widget.
Why do I get always the page 1 displayed? 
If I call the page 2, the link looks like this: `?tx_gbpartner_partnerlisting[%40widget_0][currentPage]=2&cHash=711721c87d5bb5b17eb8da3fd66b1102`
In the pagination index.html I do {pagination} and get:

```
   pages => array(3 items)
   current => 1 (integer)
   numberOfPages => 3 (double)
   displayRangeStart => 1 (integer)
   displayRangeEnd => 3 (integer)
   hasLessPages => FALSE
   hasMorePages => FALSE
   nextPage => 2 (integer)
```

The pagination widget doesn't understand the param currentPage. What could be here wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is default view for paginate viewhelper, displayed always 1. We are able to change pagination view you can change default widget template.
Add following settings into your `ext/YourExtensionName/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt`

```
plugin.tx_YourExtensionKey {
    view { 
    widget.TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_YourExtensionKey.view.templateRootPath}
    }
    settings{
        pagebrowser {
           itemsPerPage         = 8
           insertAbove          = 0
           insertBelow          = 1
           maximumNumberOfLinks = 10
       }         
    }
}
```

Another thing is that you have to copy/add widget template file into your templates directory, you can copy this template file from `typo3/sysext/fluid/Resources/Private/Templates/ViewHelpers/Widget/Paginate/Index.html`
and make new directory structure like this:

```
/Templates/ViewHelpers/Widget/Paginate/Index.html
```

Index.html is your copied file.
now you can customize or add your own design layout in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to disable caching for the page with the plugin on it? I would guess it's a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

The paging is only applied within the paginate widget, if you debug something in your controller you will always have the same result.

The paginate widget takes the queryresult as parameter, extracts the query object, adds limit/offset params to the sql and retrieves the slice of records.

Thats how it works.

To help you i would need to see your controller action and fluid template.